# How to store "types" and instantiate them dynamically in typescript?

Tags: typescript, reflection, instantiation

I'm trying to accomplish a similar behavior that I can do with `C#`. In `C#` I can use reflection to dynamically instantiate a class based on the `Type` class. The following code shows how to do in `c#`, rather simple:

```
interface IHandler
{
   void Handle();
}
var handlers = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
  { "querydom", typeof(QueryDomHandler) },
  { "other", typeof(OtherHandler) },
};

var type = handlers["querydom"];
var instance = (IHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
instance.Handle();
```

How can I accomplish the same with `typescript`? I've sketched the following code, but I do not know how to get a "Type" from a class (`QueryDomCommandHandler`), or how to instantiate a class dynamically without using its name ( `new QueryDomCommandHandler()`).

```
let handlers = [];
handlers[CommandType.QueryDom] = QueryDomCommandHandler; //how to store the "type"?

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message: Command, sender, sendResponse) => {
    logger.debug(`${isFrame ? 'Frame' : 'Window'} '${document.location.href}' received message of type '${CommandType[message.command]}'`);
 
    const handlerType = handlers[CommandType.QueryDom];
    const handlerInstance = ????? //how to instantiate the class?
    if (message.command == CommandType.QueryDom) {
        const handler = new QueryDomCommandHandler(message as RulesCommand);
        const response = handler.handle();
        sendResponse(response);
        return true;
    }
    else if (message.command == CommandType.Highlight) {
        const handler = new HighlightCommandHandler(message as RulesCommand);
        handler.handle();
    }
});
```

Any insights?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answers, here's my solution, although I would like to use the `enum` instead of the hardcoded string in the `Record`, but couldn't figure it out:

```
const handlers: Record<string, (new () => commands.CommandHandlerBase)> = {
    'QueryDom': QueryDomCommandHandler,
    'Highlight': HighlightCommandHandler,
    'ClearHighlight': ClearHighlightCommandHandler,
};

    const handlerType = handlers[commands.CommandType[message.command]];
    const handler = new handlerType();
    const response = await handler.handle(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple. You just need to use the `Map` class instead of the `Record`:

```
type WorkerHandlerConstructor = (new () => handlers.CommandHandlerBase);

handlers: Map<types.CommandType, WorkerHandlerConstructor> = new Map<types.CommandType, WorkerHandlerConstructor>([
    [types.CommandType.Click, handlers.ClickCommandHandler],
    [types.CommandType.Navigate, handlers.NavigateCommandHandler]
]);
```

And then

```
const handlerType = handlers.get(types.CommandType.Click);
const handler = new handlerType();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: you can not get "type" in typescript because the type not exist in the runtime, what you get is the *constructor of the class* actually.

you will need some type on the `handlers` array first to make the inference works:

```
let handlers: (new (...arg: any[]) => CommandHandler)[] = [];
```

> modify the `CommandHandler` part to the name of the base handler class

to create a instance after get the constructor, just `new` it, the *class name* itself is not important:

```
const handlerInstance = new handlerType()
//    ^? const handlerInstance: CommandHandler
```

---

Solution for the **Update** part:

Use `satisfices` keyword on the `handlers` is what you want:

```
const handlers = {
    [CommandType.QueryDom]: QueryDomCommandHandler,
    [CommandType.Highlight]: HighlightCommandHandler,
    [CommandType.ClearHighlight]: ClearHighlightCommandHandler
} satisfies Record<CommandType, (new () => commands.CommandHandlerBase)>

if (message.command == CommandType.QueryDom) {
    const handlerType = handlers[message.command];
    const handler = new handlerType();
    //    ^? const handler: QueryDomCommandHandler
}
```

And enum key can be used as an object key like above.

> Note: `satisfies Record<string, (new () => commands.CommandHandlerBase)>` has similar effect, but I think use `CommandType` would be more clear.

Comment: I tried to simplify my question. The `CommandHandler` is actually a **generic** type: `interface CommandHandler<TCommand extends Command, TResponse>`. Your `handlers` is very weird and hard to understand. Is it an array?

Comment: Oh I just realize your confusing, yes it is an array of "command constructor" because I saw you assign `[]` to the `handlers`. It should be a `Record` like what you describe later and I just updated my answer.

Comment: sorry, the `satisfies` requires all enum values to be presented, but I won't have all handlers there.