# Typescript satisfies condition with Record and generics does not work

Tags: typescript, reflection, typechecking

This question is related to my other one [How to store "types" and instantiate them dynamically in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536976/how-to-store-types-and-instantiate-them-dynamically-in-typescript).

Now I'm trying to add generics and abstract base classes into the mix. VsCode complains about everything. And I've tried to tweak the `satisfies` condition, but nothing works.

Here's the smallest reproducible [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIVaghogEwBUBPMYOAbwCg47MAbASwGMBrOAXjgHINn2PADS16AOWAB3IrgBGXXhOlzh1AL7VqoSLDhNEMYFABmuFhQCCyGNlwwmERFhz4CVUXSYEAXHADOMFD6AOYA3B5wMGTAvs54hKTk4Rpa4NDw+oYmZhQyslY2ePaOca4IIIaEfnAFtsVO2PFuNPR6Pv6BIeGtUeSxja6JwN30MHIAku0oqLJG6pra6XByAVBm8CwMuH7VAMrADMAsNlClhHqoYIeoSDDVebVFDg0u5y30Xr6rIQo8POERFiOVbIY7QAAUYGQsgEkWi-VexGiQjgUJhrEiEymaFmUBRaNhfgORxOX06iGCAEoqHANClFrpNttqvxWGwzm5QJUCHtiWDTgM3oDgYFQSdwWNZJNfNNcSiiYd+WSghTqe9WnQ-MhyFBwRyhgA6VnsFGSybyvknSkjOh0hZpRlbHZwJR5DkXK7AG4GaqPOzPd3quF9TCCpHkBT66IG11yG1tZU-bh-AGtIGIEH8yHQ2HIKAMAD8idVNLtqR0GydvusdWeACVgH5IBngAAeIgNpvA4AAPncaZFUDFEIJGM+HRVwXxOYxBDsuF8HcbzaJatp83LS0yRlM5lDiIAEq5DlB2+6uUgeTUa08SmGUUuuy2+0GABbH4DgoGIxccym+AAFKBsCYIlWz9epOxXNtH2gnse2Se0K2WWRVnWOAmWdN0wyPQgTzPMNym5e45AggN7zgWDuz7JhLmuW4WRwj9TyIDkHyg6j+3odNM3FNcUlaFZAnQ988M-b8ml-MN-zgICQLAsjHA4lt22Uol4MQzdHWZRg2Q5XCCBPIjLxI2R9OY1tjXZCjZAgCBDnwF9NEEvwSEQFg4FEwzxLDWIBGsxEZLk1BQLbRTEDUttbPs4BHKcjU6BgV9gMkOAAFEoGA3UeEQCAMjor1bmAAgeGtCIywZSsdNjMymLEqAPXon19yaAz8Jqti4FlIweyDHjRSzfjnPobY3I8rzDi-XyXSkbDAsA4CQoUm9-SU5du1bbqoHgriNSSlL0syiEcryxrCoMYrSvjMsAHoboAITSgAZAB5AB1OAABEXrS3YXReog4Del66wAaWofrPOY6puCDVoAG0o3II1-IAXT8vS6u8vEIgRpHgBjWa5HRmblFqw9mJEVo1H8f0-GMJhGzgBsgSgAhLLDIYUXBRApDgAiXE5CoTOvQpVpeJp2PW59wWpTg+3M+qBbwAgpafdTKQQzRRvcuBjGQdz6nKI5rBg89haqUXazvRE1bgqaf0ov8FvksKVsg6WwKo58nNx7iRSh+qhgUCajD8eGJNcA1emAVH41aJhjDgcEAEJQ6gIZKT9hL9ogVKMqy8EAAMxAgQPsb1iADbcYxoAwwiY94AASShI8IaPojUHgi6z7P64zeB04UXnUvToZZfj+goGAGA80QZZJFwJhB+Yg1Q4dpoyupoA) code:

```
export enum CommandType {
    Click = 'Click',
    NewTab = 'NewTab',
}

export interface AutomationCommand {
    id: string;
    type: CommandType;
}

export interface TabAutomationCommand extends AutomationCommand {
    id: string;
    type: CommandType;
    tabId: number
}

export abstract class SelectorCommand implements TabAutomationCommand {
    id: string = '';

    constructor(public type: CommandType, public tabId: number, public selector: string) { }
}

export class ClickCommand extends SelectorCommand {
    constructor(tabId: number, selector: string) {
        super(CommandType.Click, tabId, selector);
    }
}

export class NewTabCommand implements AutomationCommand {
    type: CommandType = CommandType.NewTab;
    id: string = '';

    constructor(public url?: string) { }
}

export class AutomationResponse<TResponse> {
    constructor(public id: string, public data: TResponse) { }
}

export interface CommandHandler<TCommand extends AutomationCommand, TResponse> {
    handle(command: TCommand): Promise<AutomationResponse<TResponse>>;
}

export abstract class TabCommandHandler<TCommand extends TabAutomationCommand, TResponse> implements CommandHandler<TCommand, TResponse> {
    constructor() { }

    abstract handle(command: TCommand): Promise<AutomationResponse<TResponse>>;
}

export class ClickCommandHandler extends TabCommandHandler<ClickCommand, boolean> {

    async handle(command: ClickCommand): Promise<AutomationResponse<boolean>> {
       throw Error('not implemented');
    }
}

export class NewTabCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<NewTabCommand, number>{
    constructor() { }

    async handle(command: NewTabCommand): Promise<AutomationResponse<number>> {
       throw Error('not implemented');
    }
}

//BELOW DOES NOT WORK
const handlers = {
        [CommandType.Click]: ClickCommandHandler,
        [CommandType.NewTab]: NewTabCommandHandler,
    } satisfies Record<CommandType, (new <TCommad extends AutomationCommand, TResponse>() => CommandHandler<TCommad, TResponse>)>;

async function execute<TCommand extends AutomationCommand, TResponse>(command: TCommand): Promise<AutomationResponse<TResponse>> {

        const handlerType = handlers[command.type];
        if (!handlerType)
            throw Error(`No handler found for command type '${command.type}'`)

        const handler = new handlerType();
        return await handler.handle(command);
    }
```

Error:

```
Type of computed property's value is 'typeof ClickCommandHandler', which is not assignable to type 'new <TCommad extends AutomationCommand, TResponse>(pageAwaiter: Awaiter, tabs: Map<number, TabSession>) => CommandHandler<TCommad, TResponse>'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new (pageAwaiter: Awaiter, tabs: Map<number, TabSession>) => ClickCommandHandler' is not assignable to type 'new <TCommad extends AutomationCommand, TResponse>(pageAwaiter: Awaiter, tabs: Map<number, TabSession>) => CommandHandler<TCommad, TResponse>'.
      Construct signature return types 'ClickCommandHandler' and 'CommandHandler<TCommad, TResponse>' are incompatible.
        The types of 'handle' are incompatible between these types.
          Type '(command: ClickCommand) => Promise<AutomationResponse<boolean>>' is not assignable to type '(command: TCommad) => Promise<AutomationResponse<TResponse>>'.
            Types of parameters 'command' and 'command' are incompatible.
              Type 'TCommad' is not assignable to type 'ClickCommand'.
                Type 'AutomationCommand' is missing the following properties from type 'ClickCommand': tabId, selector
```

This should be simple, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why would you need generics with the `satisfies`. You can simply replace the condition to `Record<CommandType, new () => CommandHandler<any, any>>`. However, you will have an error when you try to invoke the function `handler.handle(command);`, which is another problem outside of this question scope. Would you like to cover it?

Comment: You say this is the "smallest" reproducible example but it really looks like there's more there than necessary to get the point across.  I took a few minutes and got it down to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKr5Gm) (there's some inline comments about how I'd think of approaching an answer to this, fwiw).  You could probably reduce it even further if you put in some effort to do that.  Ideally it should fit on a single screen to make it easier to focus on finding a solution without having to scroll around.

Comment: (see prev comment) and the solution as per ms/TS#47109 looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJrQvW) possibly.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (after you [edit] to minimize the example to fit). If not, what am I missing?